# Additional Partitions of 537 MB with "$RECYCLE.BIN" and "System Volume Information"? Is it ok to delete some?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, xubuntu

i'm not entirely sure what these partitions are, and im not really sure what to search about them passed there contents, but I have 4 fat32 partitions of 512 MB, just containing two folders "$RECYCLE.BIN" and "System Volume Information".

I'm not that familiar with the linux install process or partitioning but i think these were created after reinstalling Xubuntu (I reinstalled it a few times, and it seems like there were more than before). So any information on these and if it would be ok to delete them would be great

Comment: $RECYCLE.BIN is a Windows file. Ubuntu (and Xubuntu) call the Trash file something else.

Comment: @user535733 do you know why i somehow wound up with 4? I forgot to mention, but I am dual-booted with windows, just reinstalled xubuntu a few times. definitely didnt have 4 before my last install. So idk why more would be made

Comment: Best to post partitions: `lsblk -f` Windows has these, if UEFI/gpt: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/configure-uefigpt-based-hard-drive-partitions#RecommendedPartitionConfigurations